# Hibernate mapping - Could not determine type for pg-uuid

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, mapping, uuid

I'm actually trying to use the Hibernate ORM with java annotations for the mapping. I use PostgreSQL for my database and its UUID type. As I have seen on others posts, when I want to map the UUID pgsql type to the UUID Java type, I should add @Type(type="pg-uuid") to every UUID fields. The problem is that it doesn't seem to be recognized by hibernate as I get this:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: pg-uuid, at table: ev_session, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(user_id)]

I can't find anything on Google mentionning that, so I really have no clue of where I should look.

Here is my mapped class. The table uses two UUID as primary key, that's why I had to create a nested class representing it. I'm not sure that I did it right though.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ev_session")
public class SessionDb {

    ////////////////////////
    // VARIABLES
    ////////////////

    @Id
    private PrimaryKey primaryKey;
    @Column(name="date")
    private Date timestamp;

    ////////////////////////
    // NESTED CLASSES
    ////////////////

    @Embeddable
    private class PrimaryKey implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7124577164356450734L;

        @Type(type="pg-uuid")
        @Column(name="user_id")
        public UUID userID;
        @Type(type="pg-uuid")
        @Column(name="key")
        public UUID token;
    }

    ////////////////////////
    // CONSTRUCTORS
    ////////////////

    public SessionDb() {
        this.primaryKey = new PrimaryKey();
    }

    ////////////////////////
    // METHODS
    ////////////////

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.primaryKey.token + " associated to " + this.primaryKey.userID + " at " + this.timestamp; 
    }

    ////////////////////////
    // GETTERS/SETTERS
    ////////////////

    public final UUID getUserID() {
        return this.primaryKey.userID;
    }

    public final void setUserID(UUID userID) {
        this.primaryKey.userID = userID;
    }

    public final UUID getToken() {
        return this.primaryKey.token;
    }

    public final void setToken(UUID token) {
        this.primaryKey.token = token;
    }

    public final Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public final void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which version of `Hibernate` are you using?

Comment: hibernate 3.2.6.ga, hibernate-annotations 3.2.0.ga, Hibernate-commons-annotations 3.2.0.Final

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should use a `Generator`:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
```

Take a look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-identifier).
Some more documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e5294).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I get it. The problem I have is that I cannot fetch from the database. Thanks anyway, it might be useful!

Answer (score 1):

In case of xml mapping you can add

```
<typedef class="org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType" name="pg-uuid" />
```

Like described in https://developer.jboss.org/thread/229747 but I don't know how to configure this with annotations.